# LibreOffice 5.1 doesn't integrate with Unity in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: unity, ppa, libreoffice

I have upgraded Libreoffice to 5.1  using official PPA. But the menus don't integrate  with Unity bar. I've already tried to uninstall and reinstall with no success. Also, I can't change the icon size or styles which is now in high contrast.

Any hints on how to proceed?

**EDIT: Removing the libreoffice-gtk3 package by `sudo apt-get remove libreoffice-gtk3` has fixed it**

[image]

Comment: Did you actually installed it from a PPA? What PPA and instructions did you follow? Are you sure you just didn't grabbed the deb files from LibreOffice website? Also as a note, all PPA are considered unofficial no matter if they have the word official on it's description.

Comment: @xangua Yes, I have installed it from this PPA: http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fully supported edition of LibreOffice in Ubuntu 15.10 is version 5.0.
This tested version is available in the official Ubuntu 15.10 repositories.

Most probably LibreOffice 5.1 will be included in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
Unity integration should work fine after the final release in April.

The [LibreOffice Fresh PPA](https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) is not an official Ubuntu repository.
It is an option for those, who want to use the latest software.

This - of course - may lead to the one or other minor issue.
It is also recommended to wait for the first point release.

You can decide whether to downgrade to version 5.0 or,
live with the situation as it is and use the latest edition.

Additional corresponding information :
[LibreOffice fails to integrate with Unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/732804/libreoffice-fails-to-integrate-with-unity/732814#732814)

**Update information 2016-03-02 :**

**LibreOffice 5.1.1** is now available in the LibreOffice Fresh PPA.
LibreOffice 5.1 integration with the Unity menu bar works now.